# How to disable haptic feedback in showTimePicker()?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, if you show a time picker by calling `showTimePicker()`, it will heavily vibrate when picking the time (in dial mode).

Is there a way to disable the time picker dialogs haptic feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b8f7f1f986/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart#L2439), you can see that everything related to vibration is private API

```
  void _vibrate() {
    switch (Theme.of(context).platform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        _vibrateTimer?.cancel();
        _vibrateTimer = Timer(_kVibrateCommitDelay, () {
          HapticFeedback.vibrate();
          _vibrateTimer = null;
        });
        break;
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        break;
    }
  }
```

```
  void _handleTimeChanged(TimeOfDay value) {
    _vibrate();
    setState(() {
      _selectedTime.value = value;
    });
  }
```

So unfortunately, the only clean way is to create your own `TimePickerDialog` and change that behavior.